# Original Redis Master does not become "good" slave after failover

Tags: replication, redis

I have setup a 3 node HA redis cluster with Sentinel monitors on each of the nodes.
I have the following configuration:
RedisA - Master
RedisB - Replica
RedisC - Replica

with 3 Sentinels watching the Master.
Everything works fine (I'm keeping all sentinels up, so no quorum problems):

1. I **stop** the **RedisA** process and it fails over to **RedisB**
   for **Master**.
2. I stop **RedisB** and it will failover and make **RedisC** **master**.
   Bring back **RedisA** and **RedisB**, they become **Replicas** as expected.
3. I stop **RedisC**, **RedisB** becomes **Master**.
4. With only **RedisB** and **RedisA** **up**, I **stop** **RedisB**. But now **RedisA DOES NOT become master** and my HA cluster breaks down.

So everything seems to be fine except the problem is that **RedisA** (the original Master) **doesn't become an eligable slave**.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem. My configuration has password authentication. The initial configuration had masterauth set for both slaves, but I did not add it to the master (since it didn't need it). When it failed over, the master became a slave, but since it didn't have the masterauth password set, it could not replicate and thus sentinel wisely refused to select it as the new master after that.
Fix: Add masterauth password to my original master (RedisA).